# Change the \frametitle font size; height also affected?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, fontsize

I want to change only the `\frametitle` font size. Changing this, is the height of the frame title going to decrease also? Because I want that.

I'm using the `Warsaw` theme.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes; changing the font size will also affect the height of the `frametitle` template. However, depending on the theme used the effect will be different; using `Warsaw`:

An image of the default frametitle height:

[image]

and with `\tiny` font size (as in the example code):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And using `CambridgeUS`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the default frametitle height:

[image]

and with `\tiny` font size (as in the example code):

[image]

The change can be locally applied to some specific frame(s), as the following example illustrates:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
Test
\end{frame}

{
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\tiny}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
Test
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @George please see my updated answer (notice the use of braces to keep the change local).

Comment: Isn't it the same (but easier) to just apply a desired font size command to a frame title's text? It seems to have the same effect. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh but if the font change has to apply to all the frames, then you would have to apply the font switch to every `\frametitle` command. Setting the `frametitle` font as in, for example, `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\tiny}` will save you having to type `\tiny` for every title.

Comment: I was thinking about a single frame change (had that need yesterday). But, in general, I agree with you - your approach is more flexible (one might need such change in more than one spot). Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Google brought me here for the same issue, and this solution didn't work for me...until I remembered I was using the `ignorenonframetext` class option.  After surrounding the `\setbeamerfont` line with `\mode<presentation>{...}` it all worked fine.